# How to simulate a loan portfolio in MatLab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, simulation, probability, portfolio

I'm pretty new to MatLab/Octave and I'm struggling with a problem I'm trying to solve.

A portfolio consists of 1,000 loans of $10,000 each, and each one has a 0.1 probability of default. Calculate the probability that 50 loans default, as well as the Expected Loss and the Variance of the portfolio. Simulate the portfolio above using Matlab/Octave.

So I calculated the probability at (1,000!/50!950!)(1/10)^50(9/10)^950
The expected loss at E(Z)=10,000E(X)=10,000np=10,000x1,000x0.1=$1,000,000
And the Variance at Var(Z)=10,000^2Var(X)=10,000^2np(1-p)=10,000^2x1,000x0,1x0,9= $9 billion

I'm really struggling with the simulation of the portfolio.

Comment: Hi George, your problem is one of applying the binomial distribution, so your calculations sound reasonable. What exactly is your question? Is it how to perform the above calculations in octave?

Comment: Yes, kind of. More of how to use the binomial distribution in an octave program to simulate the portfolio. Calculations in their own should be pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most straightforward way (in my opinion) to implement this in octave.

```matlab
%%% The Portfolio problem:
    pkg load statistics;   % required for the `binopdf` and `binostats` functions

  % Problem variables
    NumberOfLoans = 1000;
    PricePerLoan  = 10000;
    ProbOfDefault = 0.1;

  % Binomial probability of 50 in 1000 loans defaulting for a binomial parameter of 0.1
    p = binopdf( 50, NumberOfLoans, ProbOfDefault );
    fprintf( 'Probability of 50 loans defaulting is %.3g\n', p );

  % Expected loss
    [ ExpNumDefaults, VarDefaults ] = binostat( NumberOfLoans, ProbOfDefault );
    ExpLoss = PricePerLoan * ExpNumDefaults;
    VarLoss = (PricePerLoan .^ 2) * VarDefaults;

    fprintf( 'Expected loss of portfolio: %d\n', ExpLoss );
    fprintf( 'Variance of portfolio: %d\n', VarLoss );
```

Output:

```matlab
Probability of 50 loans defaulting is 3.21e-09
Expected loss of portfolio: 1000000
Variance of portfolio: 9000000000
```

This makes use of the `statistics` package, which you can install from an octave terminal like so (the `-forge` option downloads this directly from the [Octave Forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/) website):

```matlab
pkg install statistics -forge
```

The reason I would use the statistics package rather than perform those calculations 'by hand' is that the intermediate steps requiring factorials would result in very large numbers, which would likely break your computations, whereas the statistics package implements these functions in an optimised manner which work around such problems.

If you are a complete beginner to octave, then there's probably a lot of new stuff happening in the code snippet above. I would suggest you read the basics of octave from the [official documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/), and also look up the functions used here directly from an octave terminal using the `help` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll definitely use the documentation you provided!